What is the fastest algorithm for classical period finding?
Let $N$ be a positive integer, and choose an integer $a$ such that $\gcd(a,N)=1$. Then $a^r \equiv 1 \,\text{mod}\, N$ for some $r$. What is the current fastest classical algorithm for finding the smallest positive $r$ satisfying this congruence?
If one chooses an $N^{th}$ root of unity $\alpha$ in a field $k$, we can define $f(x) = \alpha^{a^x}$, which is a periodic function from $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow k$ with period $r$. The Fourier transform of $f$ is $(Ff)_i = \sum_j \alpha^{ij + a^j}$. Does diagonalizing the DFT matrix help to speed up computation of this sum?

Do you specifically want the least such $r$ or just some such $r$?

Just some such $r$. I'm also just seeing this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4509061/time-complexity-of-classical-period-finding

if you could find periods fast, wouldn't that imply fast factorization?

@kodlu Yes, I don't think there's a polynomial time algorithm, I'm just curious what already exists. I've edited the question to just ask for the multiplicative order.

I believe the fastest known method is to factorize $N$ and $\phi(N)$ and then simply try all factors of $\phi(N)$

@DanielWeber So essentially the two problems are equivalent. I guess I'm surprised there are no period finding methods which do not rely on first factoring.

This works only if you know the factorization of $N$ thus can compute $\phi(N)$ efficiently:
First find out the largest power of $2$ dividing $\phi(N):=M.$ This can be done in $\log N$ steps. Let $M=2^uM'.$ Since the order of $a$ must divide $M$ one can check the values
$t\in\{M',2M',2^2M',\ldots,2^uM'\}$ to see if $a^t=1.$
The complexity of obtaining the factorization of $N$ is given by the complexity of the NFS determined by the largest prime factor of $\phi(n).$ Otherwise, it seems to me finding the period of $r$ more efficiently would lead to a more efficient factoring algorithm.

So this a clear direction from factoring to period finding. The quantum algorithm relies on fast period finding. Are there no classical algorithms for period finding which don't first factor $N$?
